# How to work with async* functions in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

I am using flutter_bloc library.

In the bloc, the `mapEventToState` method is an `async*` function which returns `Stream<BlocState>`. 
From this function I am calling other `async*` functions like this `yield* _handleEvent(event)`

In such method, I am calling some Future returns functions but in the Future `then()` function it wont let me call other yield* functions.

Here is an example:

```
Stream<BlocState> mapEventToState(BlocEvent event) async*{
     yield* _handlesEvent(event); //This calls to worker method 
}

Stream<BlocState> _handleEvent(BlocEvent event) async* {
   _repository.getData(event.id).then((response) async* { //Calling Future returned function
         yield* _processResult(response); //This won't work
     }).catchError((e)  async* {
         yield* _handleError(e);  //This won't work either
     });

   Response response = await _repository.getData(event.id); //This do works but I want to use it like above, is it possible?
   yield* _processResult(response); //This do works
}
```

The question is however, how to combine between Future and Stream in dart.
I could use `await _repository.getData` which works. but then I won't catch the error.

Comment: use simple `await` instead of `then`: `var response = await _repository.getData(event.id); yield* _processResult(response);`

Comment: Thanks, I've mentioned this in my question, how do I catch the error like this? I wanted to use the built in catch error of the Future api.

Comment: use normal try-catch - what does not work that way?

Comment: Thanks, please refer my reply to @Candace below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `await` is just syntactic sugar for `.then()`, and putting `await` in a `try`-`catch` block is syntactic sugar for using `.catchError`.  Things that you can do one way can be done with the other.
2. In your first version that uses `.then()`/`.catchError()`, your function doesn't return anything.
3. Your callbacks won't work because you're using `yield*` in them, but you haven't specified the callbacks with `sync*` or `async*`.  To avoid name collisions, the `yield` keyword requires them (in the same way that `await` requires a function use `async` or `async*`).

Here's a version that should work with `.then()` and `.catchError()`:

```dart
Stream<BlocState> _handleEvent(BlocEvent event) async* {
  yield* await _repository.getData(event.id).then((response) async* {
    yield* _processResult(response);
  }).catchError((e) async* {
    yield* _handleError(e);
  });
}
```

Note that the callbacks don't need to use `yield*`; they could just return their `Stream`s directly:

```dart
Stream<BlocState> _handleEvent(BlocEvent event) async* {
  yield* await _repository.getData(event.id).then((response) {
    return _processResult(response);
  }).catchError((e) {
    return _handleError(e);
  });
}
```

But (as everyone else has noted) using `await` instead of the `Future` API simplifies the whole thing (especially since we're already using `await` anyway):

```dart
Stream<BlocState> _handleEvent(BlocEvent event) async* {
  try 
    response = await _repository.getData(event.id);
    yield* _processResult(response);
  } catch (e) {
    yield* _handleError(e);
  }
}
```

See https://dartpad.dartlang.org/fc1ff92e461754bdb35b998e7fbb3406 for a runnable example.

Comment: Thanks, of course,  the _processResult and _handleError are generators which eventually yields the final State to the steam. yield won't work in the callbacks either as they are closures.

Comment: @MotiBartov I don't understand what you mean by "yield won't work in the callbacks either as they are closures".  I'm saying you need to change `(response) { yield* ...  }` to `(response) async* { yield* ... }`.

Comment: I've tried this, it won't work.  The (respose){} is actually an internal object no? The scope of it doesn't allow to yield* or yield to the stream of the outer class function

Comment: `(response) { ... }` constructs an anonymous function.  You absolutely can add `async, `async*, `sync*` to anonymous functions.

Comment: Generally you're correct, but remember that these outer function returns Stream<BlocState>, the anonymous function return type not defined so even I'd I set it async* its not the same stream. When I tried this it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `try-catch` block instead. It works for me with await operations.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this but the Future api already has catch error api, I just wondered if I can use it. It's like wrapping try-catch with another try-catch

Comment: @MotiBartov It's not *wrapping* anything.  The Dart compiler will automatically convert `try { await future; } catch { ... }` to an appropriate `future.then().catchError()` construct.  It's syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0):

To handle errors in an async function, use try-catch:

```
try {
  Response response = await _repository.getData(event.id)
} catch (err) {
  print('Caught error: $err');
}
```